# Big O Complexity - Double loop with max range from the first loop

Tags: python, loops, big-o

```
def Arithmetic (n):
    for i in range (1, n):  
        for j in range (1, (i + 1) / 3):  
            a = n^i - j/3  
    return a
```

How do I determine the Big O for this algorithm? Given that the second loop has a maximum with the first loop result.

Comment: your code doesn't run

Answer (score 0):

It's `O(n^2)`. Big-O doesn't track runtime. It tracks *how much the runtime changes* as the size of the input changes. Your runtime here is very similar to Selection Sort, which runs on a slightly smaller section of the list each time:

```
n + (n-1) + (n-2) + (n-3) + (n-4) + ...
```

Selection Sort is known as one of the `O(n^2)` sorting algorithms, meaning that as its input gets bigger linearly, its runtime increases quadratically.

Your function is like that. See the same pattern:

```
n/3 + (n-1)/3 + (n-2)/3 + ...           = 1/3 * (n + (n-1) + (n-2) + ...)
```

Since big-O notation ignores the *factor* 1/3, it's evident your function is `O(n^2)`. Its runtime will increase quadratically as the size of the input increases linearly.

---

(as a sidenote, you need to rework what's happening with `a` in your algorithm. The way you have it, it's just getting overwritten constantly. You might want to set it to 0 at the beginning, and change the other line to have `+=` or something instead of `=`.